# Scale ImageView. MultiScreen

Tags: android

Im using this code.

```
    Resources r = MainActivity.ct.getResources();
    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200,r.getDisplayMetrics());
    View inflatedLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null, false);
    inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage).getLayoutParams().width *= px / 540;
    inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage).getLayoutParams().height *= px / 960;
```

But i have app crash. How i can change width and height my imageView layout ? Thx.

Comment: please share the full code or logCat

Comment: Your are writing this code withing MainActivitiy so y are u using MainActivity.ct.getResources() reason what so ever please check the the value of Resource r =  MainActivity.ct.getResources() ; after calling this if its returning null valur to r app will crash bcz of NPE. instead calling on static variable of context to get the resource u can call Resource r=getResource(); and code will work fine

Comment: yeah, thank you for answer. I get always normal value, not null. But i can't change layout size. If i insert this code in async class, which downloading image and creating bitmap for _thumbImage_ then code will work fine, but it's not correct for me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Resources r =  getResources();
```

use this code if u R CALLING WITHING THE MAINACTIVITY 
ELSE USE CONTEXT VALUE ONLY CONTEXT VALUE LIKE THIS

```
 Context ct;//in class 
Context ct=MainActivity.this;//in oncreate() menthod
Resource r =ct.getResource();//in your code
```

or in you case if you make the Context ct as

```
static Context ct;//in class
ct=MainAcitivity.this;// in oncreate() function
```

call in your code

```
Resource r=MainAcitivity.ct.getResource();
```

but its not a good practice to store a context as stactic variable unless it last option only to use like this

```
 float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200,r.getDisplayMetrics());
    View inflatedLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null, false);
    inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage).getLayoutParams().width *= px / 540;
    inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage).getLayoutParams().height *= px / 960;
```

Comment: share the code where and how you are doing and its not working for you  may then is easy for all to suguest you the answer as you are looking

Comment: yes, this code is working now. Just  I can't get used to android studio after another develop environments. that's my mistake. sorry:) and ty one more time

Comment: @AndreevVladimir vote for the answer so it will help others to find this solution easily without wasting time.